# Multi event Trigger syntax

Tags: db2, audit

I have a db2 LUW 10.5 database.

I want to create a trigger that saves a copy of a record into an audit table whenever, a record gets updated and inserted.

I came up with follwing syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_TRANSACTION_MESSAGE_CREATE_HIST
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON TRANSACTION_MESSAGE REFERENCING NEW AS N FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL 
BEGIN ATOMIC
    INSERT INTO ....
END@
```

I get following error message when creating the trigger:

> An unexpected token "OR UPDATE" was found following "".  Expected
>   tokens may include:  "".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.16.53

However, if I create it as an insert only trigger i can create the trigger succeesful. The same is true when creating an update only trigger.

Any idea what is wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000931.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-105&lang=en), *"If multiple events are specified, the triggered action must be a compound SQL (compiled) statement (SQLSTATE 42601)"*.

`BEGIN ATOMIC` indicates an *inlined* compound SQL statement. You'll have to replace it with `BEGIN` to make it *compiled*.

It might be worth noting the difference between the inlined and compound SQL in case of a trigger. An inlined compound statement becomes part of the triggering statement execution plan, while the compiled compound statement is invoked much like a stored procedure would be, with the associated overhead. Subsequently, triggers with inlined statements might perform a bit better, which may become noticeable on a heavily loaded system.